# Applications of functional calculus?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

What problems other then spectral theory are related to the development of the idea of a algebra homomorphism $\pi_{A}: f \rightarrow f(A)$

Also what functions are important other then projections(characteristic funtions)?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus#Spectral_projections

Comment: Entire functions?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that "projections are functions of interest in the setting of functional analysis"?  Surely, they are "of interest", but that seems like a bit of an understatement.  It might help if you could provide some more context; is there some usage of functional analysis that you're trying to understand?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom more like the general idea. Projections as in the context of spectral theory / invariant subspaces.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I cant even figure out why those are usefull. We have the spectral mapping theorem for instance but I cant see what anyone would get or be able to solve from that relation.

Comment: The idea is that given a function $f(x)$ (such as a polynomial or $f(x) = e^x$), we want to be able to sensibly define $f(A)$ for an operator $A$.  Have you at least seen why this is a useful thing to do for matrices (e.g. in differential equations and dynamical systems)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ah! I know a little about it, ill look into more, thx. That takes care about the entire functions aswell..

Comment: The reason is that the spectral mapping theorem can be very useful to figure out the spectrum of an operator. For instance, the Fourier transform has the property that $\mathcal{F}^4 = I$. It is pretty easy to prove that it has eigenvalues of $\pm 1,\pm i$. It would be nice to say something about the rest of its spectrum. If you define $f(z) = z^4$, then $f(\mathcal{F}) = I$ and moreover the spectral mapping theorem tells you that $f(\sigma(\mathcal{F})) = \sigma(f(\mathcal{F})) = \sigma(I) = \{1\}$. Thus the spectrum of the Fourier transform is exactly $\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functional calculus for selfadjoint and normal operators requires projections and integrals.

The holomoprhic functional calculus deals with general linear operators, but less general functions of those operators. For example, if $C$ is a positively-oriented simple closed rectifiable curve enclosing the spectrum of a bounded operator $A$ on a complex Banach space, then
$$
              F(A) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}f(z)\frac{1}{zI-A}dz,
$$
where $\frac{1}{zI-A}$ suggestively for $(zI-A)^{-1}$. The function $F$ may be holomorphic on a neighborhood of the spectrum, which may require using a system of contours enclosing components of $\sigma(A)$. Even for matrices, this is not simple. For a matrix $A$ on $\mathbb{C}^N$, the operator $(zI-A)^{-1}$ has poles at the eigenvalues of $A$, and the order of the pole is the size of the largest Jordan block associated with $A$. Nilpotent operators play an important role in the functional calculus for $A$, the series expansion of $\frac{1}{zI-A}$ around $\lambda$ has the form
$$
             \frac{1}{zI-A} = \sum_{n=-N}^{\infty}A_n(z-\lambda)^{n},
$$
where
\begin{align}
         A_{-n} & = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-\lambda| = r} (z-\lambda I)^{n-1}(zI-A)^{-1}dz \\
      & = (A-\lambda I)^{n-1}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-\lambda|=r}(zI-A)^{-1}dz \\
      & = (A-\lambda I)^{n-1}P,
\end{align}
where $P = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z-\lambda|=r}(zI-A)^{-1}dz$ is a projection. Only the singular terms contribute to the integral for $F(A)$, and these give
$$
      F(A) = F(\lambda)P + \frac{F'(\lambda)}{1!}(A-\lambda I)P+\cdots+\frac{F^{(N-1)}(\lambda)}{(N-1)!}(A-\lambda I)^{N-1}P + \mbox{ terms at other eigenvalues }.
$$
The absence of higher or terms happens because $(A-\lambda I)^{N}P=0$, where $N$ is the size of largest Jordan block with eigenvalue $\lambda$. The operator $(A-\lambda I)P$ is nilpotent of order $N$: because $(A-\lambda I)P=P(A-\lambda I)$ and $P^2=P$, then
$$
          [(A-\lambda I)P]^{n} = (A-\lambda I)^{n}P,\;\;\; n \ge 1 \\
          [(A-\lambda I)P]^{N} = 0.
$$

So projections are not enough, even for the functional calculus of a finite square matrix.

Comment: Sorry about late replay. When you say that "The functional calculus for selfadjoint and normal operators requires projections and integrals". Do you refer to the setup of the spectral integral of the operator then?

Comment: @user84647 : Yes, that's what I'm referring to there. I could have been more clear about restricting to integral formulations, because there are other methods employing von Neumann algebras, $C^*$ algebras, etc.. The holomorphic functional calculus is an integral-based approach, and I was drawing a comparison between integral approaches.